# how to parse json with ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson

i got problems when i try to parse json with ObjectMapper and in the json there is an number that look like mate

json

```
{ "_id" : 290365351583, "my_number" : 1.5638694276102368E8 }
```

my code

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
DBobject obj = ;\\the json when i select it from mongo db
String data = JSONSerializers.getStrict().serialize(obj);
JsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(data);
```

when i run this code i got ERROR "Non-standart token 'Infinity': enable JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS to allow"

Comment: Did you try enabling JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS ?

Comment: I think it's unable to parse the decimal in `my_number` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this maven dependency : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160212

It's very simple to understated and use.
ex:

```
JSONObject obj = "YOUR_JSON_STRING";
String result = obj.getString("YOUR_STRING_KEY");
```

There you can use alot of methods like: getInt(), getDouble(), getBoolean() etc.

Useful examples are there : http://crunchify.com/java-how-to-parse-jsonobject-and-jsonarrays/